# Ao mandar objeto Java de um app android para a base de dados um dos atributos vai como null

Tags: java, android

```
Produto produto = new Produto();

produto.setNome(edtNome.getText().toString());
produto.setPreco(Double.parseDouble(edtPreco.getText().toString().replace(",", ".")));
produto.setUnidMedida(txtUnidMedida.getText().toString());
```

estou tentando enviar o objeto produto com os dados acima mas quando envio para salvar o Android Studio imprime a seguinte mensagem e no banco salva nome e preço mas a unidade de medida vai como null.

> InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@5283aa8c attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@52903534

//Codigo TextView

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_produto);

    txtUnidMedida = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUnidMedida);

            txtUnidMedida.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ad.show();
                }
            });
            //Criando o AlertDialog para a lista de unidades
            unidades = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.unidades_medida);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.selecione_unid_med);
            builder.setItems(unidades, this);
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, null);
            ad = builder.create();
    }

    @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
            String itemSelecionado = unidades[position];
            txtUnidMedida.setText(itemSelecionado);

        }
```

Comment: Se puder apresentar mais partes de seu código, poderíamos lhe ajudar melhor!

Comment: A váriavel  txtUnidMedida é um EditText? Antes de salvar os seus dados utilize o Log.i("variavel", "valor"); para verificar se os valores passados estão corretos.

Comment: é um TextView com style de EditText style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" ao clicar nele abre um Dialog para selecionar a unidade de medida e deixei o campo como enable="false"

Comment: O problema estará de facto nesse `TextView`. Coloque o código que abre esse `Dialog` e que atribui o valor ao `TextView`

Comment: Fiz o seguinte, coloquei um Log.d para pegar o valor da unidade de medida  do objeto produto  Log.d("NGVL", "produto----"+produto.getUnidMedida()); e me retornou o seguinte:  com.app.retrofit D/NGVL: produto----Pacote

Comment: É pra você fazer isso antes de salvar, se você colocou isso antes de salvar e a mensagem impressa foi "com.app.retrofit D/NGVL: produto----Pacote", então significa que a sua váriavel já não está com null e sim com o valor "Pacote".

Comment: Sim foi esse o resultado que obtive mas quando chamo o método para inserir no banco dentro dele coloqueu um print da mesma forma e ele me retorna no produto.getUnidMedida() null